# Routing with Angular 4 and Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I use Angular 5 and Spring boot (Jhipster) on the backend.
When I start `npm start` and refresh some url, for example "http://localhost:9000/page" I get `Cannot GET /page`.
How to configure my project to handle browser resfresh during development?

Comment: any compile errors ?

Comment: no, application works perfectly

Comment: Your are probably not redirected to the index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you will generate a default project with **ng new appName** the node.js will manage your basic app configurations, and when you will change your code the project will be recompiled and the angular server will be restarted too:

Se the link bellow; the are all commands with options:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli